# Programmatically add a UIButton to a Storyboard View

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, storyboard

I have a Storyboard View Controller (with my own custom sub class) of which I have a initWithCoder custom method, where I want to popular the view with my own custom objects (I want to maintain the flexibility of doing this programmatically.

Code works fine until `[self.view addSubview:button];` is called, then it crashes with: "Could not load NIB in bundle".

All I wanted to do was add a UIButton on my view...

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)aDecoder 
{
    if(self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]) 
    {
        [self initLoginForm];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)initLoginForm
{

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(100, 170, 100, 30);
    [button setTitle:@"Login..." forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(handleLoginAttempt) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [self.view addSubview:button]; 

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about putting the button in the `viewDidLoad` method, then add it in the `initLoginForm`.

Something like this:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(100, 170, 100, 30);
    [button setTitle:@"Login..." forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(handleLoginAttempt) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}

-(void)initLoginForm {

[self.view addSubview:button];

}
```

or add it in the `viewDidLoad` then hide it, then in the `initLoginForm` show it.

Comment: I'm just calling initLoginForm on viewDidLoad, and inside initLoginForm I add it to the view, hope thats ok

Comment: its okay. did it still crash?